# Is it possible to hack the spring-security-core plugin @Secured annotation to be able to reference request params given to a controller?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using `Grails 2.3.3` and `spring-security-core:2.0-RC4` plugin.

I am trying to protect a controller action by securing it depending on the result of a method call from a service that takes a parameter. This parameter should be something inside the request parameters.

I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
@Secured("@mySecurityService.myCustomCheck(params.id)")
def myAction(){
    //do some things
}
```

I managed to be able to do the following:

```
@Secured("@mySecurityService.myCustomCheck()")
```

but now I have no idea how to access the request parameters that are sent to the controller.

Is it even architecturally possible to reference `params` variables inside the `@Secured` notation?

PS: I know you'll ask me to use `spring-security-acl` plugin. My problem is that it also adds a bunch of other things that I don't think I require.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2.0 you can use a closure as the annotation's check; there's a brief writeup and example in the docs: https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v2/guide/newInV2.html

You'd express your example as this:

```
@Secured(closure={
    ctx.mySecurityService.myCustomCheck(
       request.getParameter('id'))
})
```

Return `true` to allow access.

Note that the `ApplicationContext` is available as the `ctx` variable, and the request as `request`; this is in addition to the other variables and methods that are available when using SpEL (see the Spring Security docs for details). `params` isn't available, but you can access values using `request.getParameter`

Comment: That works but I have done it differently: I managed to call the service with `@mySecurityService`.

I had tried to play around with request to see if I could get params in any way but if it isn't available then I'll have to parse the URI of the web request then.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself that well, or perhaps I'm missing something. Won't `request.getParameter('id')` only work if the parameter comes like `http://example.com/myController/myAction?id=1`? I have tried like you showed but it didn't work. My id comes like `http://example.com/myController/myAction/id`.

Comment: Right, that would be a problem. I'll add in `params` as an available variable for 2.0 final, but for now you can access it with `request['org.codehaus.groovy.grails.WEB_REQUEST'].params`

Comment: Thanks. You've given me enough help to make this work for now.